# str timestamp to mysql timestamp in python

Tags: python, mysql, unix-timestamp

I am trying to store unix timestamp in mysql with mysql timestamp but when I try to do that it shows 0000-00-00 00:00:00 in mysql

the way I have tried are as follows

table structure in mysql id name timestamp
whare id is auto name is varchar and timestamp is timestamp

```
sql query is "INSERT INTO stocks (ticker, timestamp) VALUES ("harry", "1607485826")"
```

I have tried another one with datetime as follows
from datetime import datetime // imported once only

```
tmpstp = datetime.fromtimestamp(1607485826)
f'INSERT INTO stocks (ticker, timestamp) VALUES ("harry", {tmpstp})'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```sql
INSERT INTO stocks (ticker, `timestamp`) 
VALUES (@ticker, FROM_UNIXTIME(@timestamp))
```

where `@ticker` and `@timestamp` are parameters placeholders.

For shown parameters values the query will be

```sql
INSERT INTO stocks (ticker, `timestamp`) 
VALUES ('harry', FROM_UNIXTIME(1607485826))
```

PS. I recommend you to rename the column `timestamp` strongly - this is reserved word in MySQL.

Comment: thank you so much @Akina you helped me a lot

Comment: sir could you please tell me what if I want to use it in python as it is not working through python